# laravel resize ,crop and watermark

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

When i crop my resized image have blank space in right and bottom of picture like this .
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sa2uk.jpg)

this is my codes :

```
// Dimention 0 is 800, Dimention 2 Image Width i need, Dimention 3 Image Height, Dimention 4 Top And 5 Left

Image::make($file->getRealPath())
        ->resize($dimentions[0], null, function ($constraint) {
            $constraint->aspectRatio();
            $constraint->upsize();
        })->crop($dimentions[2], $dimentions[3], $dimentions[4], $dimentions[5])
        ->insert('asset/images/watermark.png', 'bottom-right', 10, 10)
        ->save('uploads/' . "$directory/" . $filename);
```